# Unique $scope variable value is not preserved using same controller

Tags: angularjs

Template:

```
<div class="textSearch">
    <input type="text" ng-model="searchText"/>
    <a href="" ng-if="searchText" ng-click="clearText()">
        <i class="fa fa-times deleteIcon" title="Clear Search" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </a>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.clearText = function () {        
    if ($scope.searchText) {
        $scope.searchText = '';
    }
}
```

I'm using this control at more than one place on the same page. All instances show their unique "searchText" value and work fine. But when I trigger the $scope.clearText() function from one of the instance, it clears textbox values for all instances. I want to clear the textbox value only of the instance I'm triggering the $scope.clearText() function from. Rest of the values should stay intact.

I'm sure this is a silly mistake. Can someone please help me?

Comment: can you post full code? there is no code showing it clears for all textboxes. is it inside a ng-repeat?

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say this is a standalone control. Which I'm using at multiple places on the same page. Each instance has exactly the same code, and it calls the same $scope.clearText() function.

Comment: are they using same ng-model?

Comment: Yes. same ng-model="searchText".

Comment: you need to have different ng-model for each ones, otherwise it will clear all the boxes

Comment: Can't reproduce: http://next.plnkr.co/edit/UkNec6mcFlEZ5L5v. But of course, I had to guess what you're actually doing. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem.

Comment: Ok, how can I do that using the same HTML Template and Controller, but without using Directive?

Comment: you need to use an array and use array[i].searchText as ng-model

Comment: @jshah You can't reference the exact same model and have it behave differently for different elements.  I would advise investing some time to understand how `ng-model` works because it will be used throughout most angularJS applications.

Comment: Thanks for your help and sorry for the trouble guys. Seems my mind is already in Friday mood. I figured out the issue. There was a flag in the parent controller which was causing the issue. Got rid of it and it works fine as @JBNizet 's plunker.  Again, my apologies for the trouble. Have a nice holiday weekend :)